# How to get the value of <li> from hover function of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

My html content is as follows,

```
<ul>
    <li class=folder>Main
      <ul>
         <li class=folder>1st fldr
            <ul>
                   <li> child1
                   <li> child2
            </ul
      </ul>

</ul>
```

Now I want to get the value of `folders`(main , 1st fldr), for that  my jquery hover method is as follow ,

```
$('ul li.folder').hover(function () {
       alert($(this).text());
});
```

but I am not getting the value can any one help me in this.

Comment: note : li tags not closed.. duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Comment: li tag not closed and ul tag also

Comment: @Lucky Your edit made drastic changes to his HTML code, which may have been the cause of his issue. Drastic changes like this should be suggested to OP, but not edited in without his consent.

Comment: @DarkAshelin As you can see the revised edit that you have rolled back is invalid html (it may work) and the <li> tags are not closed and the class elements are missing the `"` and I edited to make it a valid markup

Comment: @Lucky Yes you did, but the problem is that his invalid HTML may have been the *cause* of his issue. If you correct his code in his question, the problem may no longer be reproducable and any answerers will not be able to find out why. In that case your suggested edit should have been an answer instead of an edit.

Comment: @Lucky Speaking generally (not just for this case), meaningful changes in code are usually not a good edit, and should probably be posted as an answer or comment instead. I'd like to take [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253264/why-is-it-performing-two-actions) to illustrate. Someone edited his code (and improved formatting) but also actually removed the small typo that caused his issue to begin with.

Comment: @Lucky If my question is "Why does `alert(foo` cause a syntax error?", you don't correct the question to "Why does `alert(foo)` cause a syntax error?", because it doesn't.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha but in this case the OP's html will work and the change i made will have no effect in that and that will also work..the point is that I made the HTML look cleaner and i edited the question after trying it with jsfiddle..

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the text node from hovered element:

```
$('ul li.folder').hover(function () {
 alert($(this).contents().filter(function() {
   return this.nodeType === 3; //get text nodes
  }).text());
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ch119m7/)**

Comment: I am not understanding , How can I write it hover method

Comment: what is 3 here, why it is only 3? , This is not the only html I have . It is a dynamic content . It is dynatree. so I may have many folders and under that many childs.

Comment: 3 is for nodetype text. if the contents are dynamic then above event should work. if folders are added dynamically then you will have to use event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <ul>
        <li class=folder><span>Main</span>
        <ul>
            <li class=folder><span>1st fldr</span>
            <ul>
                <li> child1</li>
                <li> child2</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>

    </ul>


    $('ul li.folder span').mouseover(function () {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/15v26hko/

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<ul>
    <li class=folder>Main
      <ul>
         <li class=folder><span>1st fldr</span>
            <ul>
                   <li> child1
                   <li> child2
            </ul
      </ul>

</ul>
```

and access value of folder like

```
$('ul li.folder').hover(function () {
       alert($(this).find('span').text());
});
```

Comment: I cant put span this is dynamicaly generating

Answer (score 0):

`clone` the root element, then find its `children` and `remove` them. The only thing will be remaining is the current element. Try with -

```
$('ul li.folder').mouseenter(function () {
   var text = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
   alert(text);
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/97zg9onb/1/)

Comment: Updated the answer. Just had to change the event. Hover is triggering twice. so changed to mouseneter.

Comment: can u look at my actual problem , http://jsfiddle.net/raghavendram040/6327rbgL/ . ur solution some problamatic for me.

Comment: I dont know what happend in my actual jsp.My jsp is so messy . I cant any of these solutions are not working in my project. but all works in fiddel.

Comment: Check the html there. Lot of missing tags.

Comment: @Raghu fix that html.